# Can you write down a chain of derivabilities?

Tags: logic

Suppose you have a sentence $A$, from which you can derive $B$, from which you can derive $C$. What is the best way to write this down? I would like to write 
$$
A \vdash B \vdash C,
$$
but I'm not sure if it 'allowed' to use multiple turnstiles in a chain.

What is in this situation best to do style-wise?

Comment: What's wrong with $A \vdash B$, $B \vdash C$?

Comment: I want it to be more like a calculation. For example:

"From $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$, we derive $\exists x P(x)$ as follows. 

$\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \vdash \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \vdash \exists x P(x)$."

Comment: Or should I use the object-language implication $\Rightarrow$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to mark is not derivability but inference.  Inferences are the atomic steps from formula to formula, by means of which derivations are constructed.

One convention for marking steps of inference is to use the sign $\therefore$.  But this doesn't work very well for derivations involving successive inferences, since an inference may have more than one premise.  Another convention is to write the conclusion of the inference underneath of the premises.

On the other hand, an expression like $\phi\vdash\psi$ means "there is a derivation of $\psi$ from $\phi$."  So without some further convention, an expression like $\phi\vdash\psi\vdash \chi$ doesn't really make sense: it sounds a bit like "there is a road from Urumqi to there is a road from Kashgar to Khotan".

One might ask "so, why not add a convention that $\phi\vdash \psi\vdash \chi$ means '$\phi\vdash \psi$ and $\psi\vdash \chi$'"?  You could if you wanted, but it's not a great idea, for the following reason.

Let $\to$ express the material conditional, so that $\phi\to\psi$ roughly means "if $\phi$ then $\psi$".  Now, this automatically gives a meaning to $\phi\to \psi\to \chi$ (following e.g., the convention that conditionals associate to the right): it means roughly the same as "if $\phi$ then if $\psi$ then $\chi$".  So, the meanings of $\to$ and $\vdash$ are quite different: the meaning of one, but not of the other, automatically makes sense in the context $\phi\cdots \psi\cdots \chi$.  Writing  $\phi\vdash\psi\vdash \chi$ obscures this difference.